# Parsing HTTP response captured by tcpdump - entity is null, but there is data after the header

Tags: java, pcap, apache-httpcomponents

I'm trying to parse an HTTP response message out of a .pcap file captured by tcpdump using [pkts.io](http://www.aboutsip.com/pktsio/) to parse the capture file and Apache httpcommons to parse the message.

While parsing the capture file, I'm appending the payload of each packet (obtained with `Packet.getPayload()`, [doc](http://static.javadoc.io/io.pkts/pkts-core/1.0.5/io/pkts/packet/Packet.html#getPayload--)) that's part of the message into `byte[] data`.

If I print `new String(data, "UTF-8")`, I get this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Server: nginx
    Date: Fri, 10 Apr 2015 04:00:04 GMT
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    Connection: keep-alive
    Keep-Alive: timeout=300
    Vary: Accept-Encoding
    Content-Encoding: gzip
    1dd
    ��������������S�n�0��+X_���
��q�b�a���������Ȓf�q��G�K�I��=���������χ/�rg�f�d"kʌ\�+1l���P
]�\^�@r�{�k��;pģ﷐�7�=t� `C+5qg�
...
```

[Full response on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Usap8FaH)

When I try to parse the HTTP message (code below), I get all of the headers okay, but `resp.getEntity()` returns `null`.

```
SessionInputBufferImpl inBuffer = new SessionInputBufferImpl(new HttpTransportMetricsImpl(), packet.getData().length);
InputStream inStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(packet.getData());
inBuffer.bind(inStream);
DefaultHttpResponseParser respParser = new DefaultHttpResponseParser(inBuffer);
HttpResponse resp = (HttpResponse) respParser.parse();
```

Where can I go from here to try and get the response body as text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When getting an entity-body, you'll need to look at both the Transfer-Encoding and Content-Encoding, and do the appropriate decoding.  See [section 4 "Transfer Codings" of RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-4).

Look at classes in HttpComponents such as ChunkedInputStream (for chunked Transfer-Encoding) and look for code that can un-gzip gzipped text (for gzip Content-Encoding).

Comment: Both of those only apply to the content of the message, though, no? (I.e. I would want to wrap the `InputStream` returned by `someHttpResponse.getEntity().getContent()`, if the entity wasn't null.)

Comment: If the HTTP response really has *no* blank line between `Content-Encoding: gzip` and `1dd`, it's malformed, as there's supposed to be a blank line (CRLF) between the header fields and the body.  If so, then you shouldn't expect it to be parseable, although HttpComponents should indicate an error.  If it *does* have a blank line, you should be getting an entity and, if HttpComponents doesn't un-chunk and decompress it for you, you'll need to hook stuff up so that it does.

Comment: Huh. I tried getting the content manually, and I'm seeing the double CRLF, and can parse it using a byte array stream wrapped in a chunked stream wrapped in a gzip stream. But the `HttpResponse` object is still returning null for the entity.

Comment: Is the response sent in more than one TCP segment?  If so, are the TCP segments being reassembled, either by your code or by HttpComponents?  Copying your pastebin item, and counting the bytes in it, indicates that it has 4225 bytes in it, which probably doesn't fit in one TCP segment, so it's presumably been reassembled.  Does that include *all* of the chunks?

Comment: Yes, it's being reassembled by my code, and yes. I'm using the same `byte[]` for the `HttpResponse` as I am for my code, and I've double-checked the packet numbers/content that should be in the message using Wireshark.

Comment: Then there's probably either a problem with HttpComponents or with the way it's being used.

Comment: @Michelle were you able to extract the response body?  It would be great to see a solution to your question.

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't able to get `HttpResponse.getEntity()` to work, so I had to parse the response myself. Here's the code I threw together. It walks through a `byte[]` containing the entire response content looking for the blank line separating the header fields and the body, and copies everything after that:

```
private byte[] getContent(byte[] message) {
    int start = -1;
    byte[] content = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < message.length; ++i) {
        if (start >= 0) {
            content[i-start] = message[i];
            continue;
        }
        System.out.print((char)message[i]);
        if (message[i] == (byte) 13 && message[i+1]==(byte)10 && message[i+2] == (byte) 13 && message[i+3]==(byte)10 ) { //CR
            start = i+4;
            content = new byte[message.length-(i+4)];
            i += 3;
        }
    }
    return content;
}
```

Then, if the response has `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` and `Content-Encoding: gzip`, I used `ChunkedInputStream` (from HttpComponents) and `GZIPInputStream` from `java.util` to get the actual content back.

```
byte[] content = getContent(packet.getData());
if (content.length > 0) {
    InputStream byteIS = new ByteArrayInputStream(content);
    SessionInputBufferImpl contentBuf = new SessionInputBufferImpl(new HttpTransportMetricsImpl(), content.length);
    contentBuf.bind(byteIS);

    ChunkedInputStream chunkedIS = new ChunkedInputStream(contentBuf);

    GZIPInputStream gzipIS = new GZIPInputStream(chunkedIS);

    while (gzipIS.available() != 0) {
        byte[] buf = new byte[128];
        gzipIS.read(buf);
        contentBuilder.append(new String(buf, "UTF-8"));
    }
    gzipIS.close();
    String contentString = contentBuilder.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. So lame that it's not apparent how to easily ready the body using DefaultHttpResponseParser.